# Add executable jar as resource so that it is copied to target folder while debugging a project in eclipse from Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible to add an executable jar as resource or something else, so that it is always copied to the output directory (i.e. target folder in case of maven project) of the Java project while debugging it from eclipse.

Comment: Doesn't this happen automatically when you place the JAR in your `src/main/resources` directory? Are you using the m2eclipse plugin or m2e? (The former requires `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on the command line, the latter uses built-in functionality).

Comment: @Duncan no it do not adds that to output directory I tried it......

Comment: What about my other question?

Comment: @Duncan I have installed m2e from eclipse market place and in About eclipse it shows an icon with Eclipse.org -m2e and it shows M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse detail when I click on it.... I do not understand what difference M2e also stands for  Maven Integration for eclipse.